# Como verificar e pegar o valor 0 ou 1 de uma string e guardar aquele numero para aquela coluna?

Tags: java

Tenho que guardar o número `0` em uma variável `desc` e `1` na variável `asc`, caso um desses valores sejam encontrados na *string*.

Como eu faço isso?

```
package testes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Ordenar {

public static void main(String[] args) {

      String desc = null;
      String asc = null;
      String coluna = null;
      List list = new ArrayList(); 
      String sampleString = "jrp_jasper.jrp_jas_nome|0;jrp_jasper.jrp_jas_sobrenome|1";

      String[] items = sampleString.split(";");
     // List<String> itemList = Arrays.asList(items);
      for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){

         if(sampleString.charAt(i) == '0'){
             desc = "0";
             System.out.println(desc);
         }else{
             asc = "1";
             System.out.println(asc);
         }

         coluna = items[i].replaceAll("[|01]", "");
         Map map = new HashMap();
         map.put(coluna, asc);
         list.add(coluna);

         // ....
```

Comment: Use equals e não sinal de igualdade quando for comparar strings. Outra coisa, o 0 e 1 não são separados por ponto e virgula, o split não vai localizar eles. Sem contar que seu loop é em cima da lista separada por ponto e virgula, o if não vai percorrer todos os chars.

Comment: me dá uma ideia melhor? por favor...

Comment: A melhor forma de se comparar Strings em Java é usar o .equals() "StringQueVcQuerComparar.equals(StringQueSeraComparada)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Troque a validação do seu `if`, usando `contains` sobre um item do vetor de strings `items`:

```
if(items[i].contains("0")){
    desc = "0";
    System.out.println(desc);
}else if((items[i].contains("1"))){
    asc = "1";
    System.out.println(asc);
}
```

Comment: vou tentar espera....

Comment: FUNCIONOU VALEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEU.